# screen orientation issues in phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, screen-orientation

I have been using phonegap build.
Recently I have encountered the need to run my app in portrait mode only for phones and in landscape mode only on tablets (same app - different orientations),from the config files I see there is no such distinction available. Does PG has the ability to do this?Is it available in PGB.
is there a Soluction for this? 
Thanks
By using below code i am fixed issues

```
 var deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";
    if(deviceType=='iPad')
    {
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
    }
    if(deviceType=='iPhone')
    {
    screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
    }
```

Comment: In your AndroidManifest, you can set your desired orientation

Comment: how do you know it's a phone or tablet?  e.g. the Samsung Note 8.0 that I'm using, can put a Sim card inside and work like a phone.  it's a hybrid!

Comment: Hi Every one,Thanks for give response i am solved this issues by using below code

Comment: I have the same needs, I don't understand why PG doesn't integrate it natively... Anyway, can you tell me where you add this part of code ?